# What do I use as the User Token to subscribe users to topics in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am sending a request to the firebase service to subscribe Firebase-authenticated users to topics:

```
POST https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1:batchAdd
```

body:

```
{
  "to": "/topics/:my-topic",
  "registration_tokens": [
        :user-token
  ]
}
```

headers:

```
Authorization: key-:app-key
Content-Type: application/json
```

I am creating the users through the API using JWT, so I assumed that sending a JWT token as the user token for subscriptions would work, however, I get the following error with a `200 Success` response:

```
{
  "results": [{
    "error": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }]
}
```

after doing this, I attempted to use the users UIDs in the `registration_tokens` array, but was met with the same error.

Is there currently a way to subscribe Firebase users to a topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, FCM subscriptions are app instance based and not authenticated user based. When you use Firebase Cloud Messaging an [Instance ID](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/) token is automatically generated for the device instance. That is the token that should be used to subscribe to topics.

The usual flow would be that once the token is generated on the device and the user is signed in to your app, you associate those to values on your server, so on your server side when you want to subscribe a user to a topic you look up their corresponding Instance ID token and use that to subscribe them.

See an Android sample of getting the IID token generation callback and sending it to the app server [here](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/messaging/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/fcm/MyFirebaseInstanceIDService.java). See similar iOS sample [here](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/blob/master/messaging/FCM/AppDelegate.m).

Comment: Thanks, this is what I suspected, I'll show this to the iOS and Android devs and see how they want to proceed with push notification delivery.